# Calculating limit of a series of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given is the following series

[image: seq]

I want to calculate the limit for $n \to \infty$.

I already recognised the geometric series $\sum_{i=2}^n a^{i}  = \frac{1}{1-a}$ for $a=e^\rho$ (since rho is supposed to be negative and $e^\rho$ muss be <1), but I am confused with $i-1$ in the exponent.

I changed the expression to:

$lim_{n\to \infty} 2+\frac {-e^\rho+(e^\rho)^n}{-1+e^\rho}$ but can't find a way to express the limit just in term of rho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series
$$
\sum_{i=2}^\infty (\exp(\rho))^{i-1}
$$
is indeed a geometric series, since the ratio of successive terms is the constant $a:=\exp(\rho)$. To evaluate the series you don't need to adjust the indices, just use the general formula
$$
\mbox{sum of geometric series} = \frac{\mbox{first term}}{1-\mbox{common ratio}},$$
valid whenever $\left|\mbox{common ratio}\right|<1$. In this case the first term ($i=2$) is $\exp(\rho)=:a$, so the series evaluates to $a\over 1-a$.

Answer (score 0):

As $n$ goes to infinity, $\lim a_n=\lim (2+\sum_{i=2}^n a^{i-1})  = \lim (2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a^{i})=2+ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a^{i}=2+\frac{a}{1-a}$